# Traefik serving SSL certificate as invalid

Tags: ssl, traefik

Traefik is setup, redirecting to https and seems to be configured correctly.  However, when I try to access my project in the browser, the certificate is untrusted with a `NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID` error:

[image]

[image]

I can SSH into the container and `cat` the certificate files and it looks like docker is mounting the files and carrying over permissions as expected.

---

Locally, I've generated my certificate:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout infrastructure/certs/mysite-dev.com.key -out infrastructure/certs/mysite-dev.com.crt -days 10000 -nodes -subj "/C=US/ST=State/L=City/O=cicd/CN=mysite-dev.com"
```

Adjusted permissions using:

```
chmod 644 infrastructure/certs/*.crt 
chmod 600 infrastructure/certs/*.key
```

**traefik-conf.yml**

```
tls:
  certificates:
    - certFile: /certs/mysite-dev.com.crt
      keyFile:  /certs/mysite-dev.com.key
      stores:
        - default

  stores:
    default: { }
```

Here's my relevant compose configuration:

```
services:

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: infrastructure/web/Dockerfile
    image: registry.gitlab.com/my-org/my-project:web
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./infrastructure/web:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.http.routers.mysite-web.entrypoints: web,websecure
      traefik.http.middlewares.mysite-web.redirectscheme.scheme: https
      traefik.http.middlewares.mysite-web.redirectscheme.permanent: true
      traefik.http.routers.mysite-web.tls: true
      traefik.http.routers.mysite-web.rule: Host(`mysite-dev.com`)
      traefik.http.services.mysite-web.loadbalancer.server.port: 80
  traefik:
    command:
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --api.insecure=true
      - --accesslog=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --entryPoints.web.address=:80
      - --entryPoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --providers.file.filename=/conf/dynamic.yml
    image: traefik:2.7
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./infrastructure/certs:/certs:ro
      - ./infrastructure/traefik-conf.yml:/conf/dynamic.yml:ro
```

Comment: The certificate is valid but it's you've generated (self-signed) and not a trusted authority for example let's encrypt that is trusted by the client (browser) by default.  One way is to add your generated public certificate to the client trust store but I am not sure if that was your intention.

Comment: @Yan I'm just trying to get this working for local development, so if there are additional steps that can be performed locally to get this working, that would be ideal.

Comment: Thats what I  figured it’s for local Dev.  Is this a browser error?  Can you just click continue? Otherwise would have to import your public cert for your pc to trust it

Comment: And actually traefik will generate self signed cert for web secure endpoint but you would still have the same issue of trust

Comment: Looks like I have to use `localhost` _and_ enable chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

Comment: That would work but not great solution as far a security allowing any self self signed certificate to be trusted when accessing via localhost.  Its "don't try this at home .. " type of things  As long as you know what you are doing   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I wasn't able to figure this one out, I ended up resolving the issue by using LetsEncrypt to provide an SSL certificate instead.  Here's my new `traefik` service:

```
  traefik:
    command:
      - --api.dashboard=true
      - --api.insecure=true
#      - --accesslog=true
      - --log.level=INFO
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --entryPoints.web.address=:80
      - --entryPoints.websecure.address=:443
      - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.dnschallenge=true
      - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.dnschallenge.provider=route53
      - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=me@mysite.com
      - --certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json
    environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
      AWS_HOSTED_ZONE_ID: ${AWS_HOSTED_ZONE_ID}
    image: traefik:2.7
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./infrastructure:/letsencrypt # this is an empty directory, to store generated json
```

Comment: where do you provide `https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory` ?

Comment: @ChangZhao I'm not sure what you mean, that isn't provided anywhere.